# Jquery Quiz - Using images in array instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple choice quiz, and I would like to use images as the options instead of using text. I tried using divs with img inside, but it doesn't work.  Is there a different method of approaching this?

```js
   

var quizData = [
  {question:"Which animal would survive in a forest?",
   answers:["Lion","Frog","Pigeon"],
   correctAnswer:2,
   feedback:"Frogs can live pretty much anywhere except for Antartica and they prefer to live at marshes, ponds,and lakes."
  },
  ]


function showQuestion(){
 $("#question").html(quizData[currentQuestion-1].question);
 $("#answer1").html(quizData[currentQuestion-1].answers[0]);
 $("#answer2").html(quizData[currentQuestion-1].answers[1]);
 $("#answer3").html(quizData[currentQuestion-1].answers[2]);
 $("#feedback").html(quizData[currentQuestion-1].feedback);
}



  <div id="answersAndFeedback">
   <div id="answer1" class="answer-box">Answer 1</div>
   <div id="answer2" class="answer-box">Answer 2</div>
   <div id="answer3" class="answer-box">Answer 3</div>
   <div id="feedback" class="hidden">Feedback goes here</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `height` to the `.answer-box` class

```
.answer-box{
    width: 600px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #666;
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And then make the images inside `.answer-box`  fill it

```
.answer-box img {
height:100%;
width:100%;
object-fit:cover;
}
```

You can adjust the `height` and `width` of the `.answer-box` to whatever you feel like, not just `600px` and `200px`

Then add the `imgs` in the tags with `ids` for each `img`.

```
<div id="answer1" class="answer-box"><img id="img1" src="/someimage.png"/></div>
```

In the `varData` have an `images` array too with img urls. Something like this.

```
       { question:"Which animal would survive in a forest?",
         answers:["Lion","Frog","Pigeon"],
         imgs:["/img/lion.png","/img/frog.png","img/pigeon.png"],
         correctAnswer:2,
         feedback:"Frogs can live pretty much anywhere except for Antartica and they prefer to live at marshes, ponds,and lakes."
        }
```

Modify `showQuestion` like this

```
function showQuestion(){
    $("#question").html(quizData[currentQuestion-1].question);
    $("#img1").attr("src",quizData[currentQuestion-1].imgs[0]);
    $("#img2").attr("src",quizData[currentQuestion-1].imgs[1]);
    $("#img3").attr("src",quizData[currentQuestion-1].imgs[2]);
    $("#feedback").html(quizData[currentQuestion-1].feedback);
}
```

So this will now change the `src` of the images and set them to the values in the `imgs` array in the `currentQuestion`.

Comment: Really appreciate the help, but how do I change the images through JS? I was wondering if there was a method to change these images through the var quizData. So for each answer, to have a corresponding image?

Comment: Modified. It now shows a way to have the img urls in the `varData` and change with each question.

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense, I don't know how I didn't think of that. Thank you so much, appreciate the help.